# AAA benefits in Europe?

Tags: driving, germany

The [Wikipedia page for the American Automobile Association (AAA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Automobile_Association#International_affiliates) mentions that members may receive reciprocal benefits from European agencies while traveling in Europe.

- What benefits does AAA membership provide in Germany?

Answer (score 8):

I think the benefits are generally reciprocal between all the clubs in the FIA (Fédération Internationale de l'Automobile), which the AAA is a member of.

The best guide I've found for overseas reciprocal benefits is provided by the New Zealand AA [here](http://www.aa.co.nz/membership/personal/benefits/reciprocal-services/). According to them, as a AAA member in Germany you'll receive Roadside Assistance provided free of charge by [ADAC](http://www.adac.de/). As the ADAC site looks to be German language only, you might find their [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADAC) useful.

Answer (score 4):

The [AAA international Benefits page](http://www.aaa.com/PPInternational/Benefits_AAA_to_Intl.html) provides several links that might be of use.  The biggest of which is [AAA Exchange Program](http://exchange.aaa.com/automobiles-travel/international-travel/international-clubs/) which shows the list of clubs in various countries and on some occasion provide the list of services that are offered by the reciprocal agreement.

[German ADAC](http://www.adac.de/) for example provides:

> Services provided to AAA members:
>
> - All members are entitled to roadside assistance and free towing to a garage, if necessary. Members should call 01802 22 22 22 or from mobile phones the short number 22 22 22. When the member travels on the motorway and uses the phone booth along the motorway to call for help, the member will receive help from ADAC.
> - Free maps and books at offices — books are in German.