# AAA benefits as member of a European automobile club? (IHG rates)

Tags: budget, bookings, hotels, automobiles

[This travel blog article](http://youhavebeenupgraded.boardingarea.com/2016/07/intercontinental-miami-presidential-suite-157-usd/) (in German) mentions that also members of a European Automobile Club can use the AAA preferred rate for booking hotel rooms with IHG (a hotel group):

> Wer bei einem europäischen Automobilclub ist, kann die AAA Rate auch benutzen. Da gibt es eine Partnerschaft.

but fails to mention any further details.

**Is there a list of the automobile clubs that qualify for this partnership?**

In a cursory search I did find mention of a partner program of the German ADAC with AAA that could give some benefits, but IHG was not mentioned in an otherwise rather detailed list.

**Is there any confirmation of this information?** (I.e. being able to use the AAA rate with IHG as a member of a European Automobile Club.) Ideally I would like to see some IHG document, or repeated personal experience.

As far as I know AAA rates can be booked all over the world so my question is not restricted to bookings in the U.S.

We have [a question about benefits for AAA members while traveling in Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/893/32134) and while it does link to [a page that mentions](http://www.aaa.com/PPInternational/Benefits_AAA_to_Intl.html) a "global discounts program" I can not extract any further info from that site.
Another cursory search for "global discounts program" send me to [this AAA site about discounts for international members coming to US / North America](http://www.aaa.com/PPInternational/Benefits_Intl_to_US.html#gsycas). It does list a bunch of hotel chains but not IHG.

Answer (score 4):

So I tweeted IHG and they asked me to get in touch with them via [their Live Chat feature.](https://www.ihg.com/hotels/gb/en/reservation/searchresult/chatFrameSet?brandcode=6c&akamaiRegion=AMER&pageidbrand=6c_hotelsearchresult&ihgSession=DDF9C98BBCF5275479B0DB0C28C7D865&searchString=[%2B29.96][-090.06]New%20Orleans,%20LA,%20United%20States&categoryID=6c_new/GB/en&pcrNumber=&type=hotelsearch&loginType=anonymous&urlType=http&iata=&controllerName=hotelsearchresult&hotelCityStateCountryCode=new%20orleans,%20la,%20usa&hotelCode=&timeOfDayAttribute=22&siteCountry=GB&destination=New%20Orleans,%20LA,%20United%20States&country=GB&beFreeCookieCreationDate=&glat=DISP&siteLanguage=en&envName=prod&akamaiSubRegion=South%20America&searchResults=16&hotelRank=1_MSYCL%7C2_MSYLA%7C3_MSYPS%7C4_MSYHA%7C5_MSYKA%7C6_MSYDT%7C7_MSYIN%7C8_MSYWB%7C9_MSYME%7C10_HVYLA%7C&brand=6c_new&language=en&akamaiCountryCode=PH)

I asked in chat if I can book the AAA rate as an ADAC member. They initially did not understand what I was asking so I guess it is not a common thing but after specifying again they said yes, it is possible. Asked for a source they said: "This information was advised by our supervisors."

So yes, but I would try to get a better confirmation.

Update:
I also tweeted ADAC and they responded me as much as:

> That partnership and related member benefits no longer exist.

It ended as of 2015 apparently. The situation remains inconclusive to me.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the ADAC site, where it lists [Members' Benefits in the US](https://www.adac.de/mitgliedschaft/mitglieder-vorteilsprogramm/international/amerika.aspx), it note that not all benefits are valid everywhere. It appears that the ADAC member uses an [AAA Discount Card](https://www.adac.de/_mmm/pdf/AAA-DiscountCard_2016_9848.pdf). The hotel chains noted on the card are Best Western, Hilton, Hyatt, Marriott, and Starwood Hotels & Resorts. The ADAC benefits with IHG are described as available in more than 500 hotels in Europe. My AAA membership in the US does not include IHG, only those hotels listed above, along another, Choice Hotels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is a few things that are not quite clear to me, could you please elaborate: 1) you write "ADAC benefits with IHG are described as available in more than 500 hotels in Europe" - what are those? can you give a source please? 2) your AAA membership does give you access to potentially cheaper rates with some IHG hotels ("AAA rate" mentioned above) even if there is not a partnership as with other hotel chains. So my question above is, can I use this AAA rate at IHG hotels as an ADAC member?

Comment: @mts, bit of a neophyte at this. the link is www.adac.de/mitgliedschaft/mitglieder-vorteilsprogramm/international/amerika.aspx (2) I interpret the answer is perhaps not, based on the arrangement between ADAC and AAA. I was going to suggest contacting IHG headquarters, which I see you did. As they're based in the UK, I'd probably contact a US-based hotel to make sure, before booking a room in this country.

Comment: Unfortunately the link does not work for me. Could you fix and edit your answer to include it? :)

Comment: @mts, so sorry...https://www.adac.de/mitgliedschaft/mitglieder-vorteilsprogramm/international/amerika.aspx

Comment: @mts, and so happens that the IGH Americas offices are here in Atlanta. I'll call them later to see (1) whether ADAC benefits can be used, (2) what discounts it offers to AAA and are they extended to ADAC members.

Comment: No worries, some answers take a while to form :) I'm afraid I still don't see that info at the link you provide but it would be amazing if you could call them. I am especially interested to know if one can use the AAA-rate with IHG hotels as ADAC member for this question and not so much about the other hotel chains. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42710/discussion-between-dorothy-and-mts).

Answer (score 3):

ADAC is a member of the "Show Your Card and Save" program, which is the international equivalency between the various automotive club programs.  Any card with the "Show Your Card" or "AAA" logos receives the discount benefits of the AAA program in the US.

So yes, you are able to use the IHG "AAA/CAA" rate.

Having said that, I've never been asked to show my AAA-equivalent card (NRMA from Australia) when using the AAA rate at various brands of hotels, despite booking AAA rates probably north of 100 times over the past 10 years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for clarification: did you also use the IHG AAA rate as a NRMA member? My question focuses on the IHG case, for other hotel chains the situation is much clearer (as you describe and as I mention in my question).

Comment: Yes. Multiple times. (Enough in fact that I have Gold status with IHG)

Answer (score 2):

As promised, I contacted IHG North American offices, asking whether ADAC members are entitled to discounts in its hotels in North America, either through ADAC membership directly or via the AAA affiliation.

The answer is no, albeit a qualified response: its reservation systems has no information about ADAC discounts in the United States, despite what you were advised by IHG Europe.  At the same time, the guest relations case manager who fielded the query suggested contacting ADAC for further clarification on its IHG benefits. For convenience, here's the section of ADAC site that describes [Members' Benefits in the US](https://www.adac.de/mitgliedschaft/mitglieder-vorteilsprogramm/international/amerika.aspx)

Noted separately, AAA does not offer members IHG discounts in North America. The hotels listed on the [AAA discount card](https://www.adac.de/_mmm/pdf/AAA-DiscountCard_2016_9848.pdf) provided to ADAC include Best Western, Hilton, Hyatt, Marriott, and Starwood Hotels & Resorts.

Comment: IHG absolutely does offer discounts to AAA members.  If you go to their website you'll see an option for "AAA/CAA Rate".